# Proving Equalities between Sets and Families of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I had a question regarding a homework problem I was given. Here's the problem:

Let $A$ be an arbitrary non-empty set and let $\mathcal{P}(A)$ denotes its power set. For each $a \in A$ define the set 
$$C_a = \{S\in\mathcal{P}(A):a \in S\}.$$
(a) Find a simple description of $\bigcup_{a\in A}C_a$ which doesn't involve the notation $C_a$. Prove your answer.

(b) The same question as (a) but instead for $\bigcap_{a\in A}C_a$.

I started just by defining some simple cases for $C_a$ when $A = \{1,2\}$, for instance,
$$C_1 = \{ \{1\}, \{1,2\} \},$$
$$C_2 = \{ \{2\}, \{1,2\} \}. $$

From this, I would think that for any arbitrary set $A$,

(a) $\bigcup_{a\in A}C_a = \mathcal{P}(A)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$

and

(b) $\bigcap_{a\in A}C_a = \{A\}$

However I'm not sure how to go about proving these. I understand I would have to show both are subsets of each other, I'm just not sure how to get started. If someone could give me a hint or a starting point, it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers are correct.

---

For $S\in\wp(A)$ the following statements are equivalent:

- $S\in\bigcup_{a\in A}C_a$
- $\exists a\in A\;S\in C_a$
- $\exists a\in A\;a\in S$
- $S\neq\varnothing$
- $S\in\wp(A)-\{\varnothing\}$

This allows the conclusion that: $$\bigcup_{a\in A}C_a=\wp(A)-\{\varnothing\}$$

---

For $S\in\wp(A)$ the following statements are equivalent:

- $S\in\bigcap_{a\in A}C_a$
- $\forall a\in A\;S\in C_a$
- $\forall a\in A\;a\in S$
- $A=S$
- $S\in\{A\}$

This allows the conclusion that: $$\bigcap_{a\in A}C_a=\{A\}$$